# How to enable JMX on Weblogic 10.x

Tags: weblogic, jmx

I have an application that is JMX enabled. It has its own JMX Agent and some MBeans. When I launch the application in WebLogic, I am able to connect to the JMX agent via the RMI url and perform the operations on MBeans via "**JConsole**".

But when I get into the Weblogic console, I can not see any JMX consoles! How can I enable the JMX console in Weblogic ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hope this helps,refer to this url -> http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=3570887

Answer (score 9):

Add the following JVM parameters to your Weblogic startup scripts:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8888 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

and restart the server. You'll be able to connect remotely via JConsole/VisualVM/etc at host:8888 then.

Comment: to add to Kristof Jozsa answer, there is a way to connect to weblogic with JConsole and JMX without having to explicitly enable a port on the server: this is described here https://blogs.oracle.com/theshortenspot/entry/accessing_jmx_for_oracle_weblo and here http://www.javamonamour.org/2012/05/weblogic-monitoring-with-jmx-and.html and I have successfully used it a number of times.

Answer (score 3):

WebLogic does not have a JMX console embedded in Administration console.

WebLogic includes [WebLogic Scripting Tool](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/wls100/config_scripting/using_WLST.html) for [accessing Other BEA MBeans and Custom MBeans](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/wls100/config_scripting/nav_edit.html#wp1014113)

Answer (score 1):

WebLogic 10.3.4+ does have an MBean browser through the Oracle Enterprise Manager Fusion Middleware Control page.

To access it, log in to the Enterprise Manager, select the WebLogic Domain from the left index, expand it and right click on your domain.

In the context menu there is an option "System MBean Browser".  Select that and you will have access to the MBeans.